# TableView and polymorphism [JavaFx]

Tags: java

There are 2 classes: `PipeCable` and `Pipe` which extends `PipeCable`.

I have a `TableView`: `private TableView<PipeCable> workshopList;`

And I'd like to add to this `TableView` an `ObservableList` of `Pipe`s:

`private ObservableList<Pipe> pipeList;`

I try to add this list to `TableView`:

```
workshopList.setItems(data.getPipeList());
```

But I get error:

> The method setItems(ObservableList< PipeCable >) in the type TableView < PipeCable > is not applicable for the arguments (ObservableList< Pipe >)

What am I doing wrong?

Comment: Either add an `ObservableList<PipeCable>` (these could actually be `Pipe` instances) or make the table `TableView<Pipe>`.

Comment: See ["Is List<Dog> a subclass of List<Animal>?"](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2745265/is-listdog-a-subclass-of-listanimal-why-arent-javas-generics-implicitly-p)

Answer (score 0):

You defined `workshopList` with the generic type `PipeCable`. So the signature is `setItems(ObservableList<PipeCable>)` and you cannot invoke this method with an `ObservableList<Pipe>`. Create your field as `private TableView<Pipe> workshopList`.

Comment: Then i will not be able to display both Cables and Pipes in one TableView.

Comment: I don't know your `data` but maybe you can change it's return type of `getPipeList` to `ObservableList<PipeCable>`. This list may also contain `Pipe`s...